# Add a second command that calls another method?

Tags: c#

I'm remaking a text-based adventure game. During the character creation, I'd like for the user, at any time, to type 'skillset' and list all the traits that a specific race has. I've tried for a couple hours and can't seem to figure it out.

This is my character creation class.

```
public string userCommand_SeachSkill;

    SkillSet searchSkill = new SkillSet();

    public void Create_Character()
    {

        // CHOOSE GENDER //
        do
        {
            validate = 0;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Are you male or female? (f/m): ");
            Sex = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();


            if (Sex == "M" || Sex == "F")
            {
                validate = 1;  
            }
            else if (Sex != "M" || Sex != "F")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must enter 'm' or 'f'");
            }


        } while (validate == 0);
```

And this is my Skill Set Class. Everything in the if/else statements are methods to print the traits of a race to the console. Let me know if there is anything else I can add to better ask my question. Thank you in advance! :)

```
ClassAttributes classes = new ClassAttributes();
Character character = new Character();
skillset = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        do
        {
            validate = 0;
            if (skillset == "HUMAN")
            {
                classes.SkillSetHuman();
            }
            else if (skillset == "ORC")
            {
                classes.SkillSetOrc();
            }
            else if (skillset == "ELF")
            {
                classes.SkillSetElf();
            }
            else if (skillset == "EXIT")
            {
                validate = 1;
                character.Create_Character();
            }

        } while (validate == 0);
```

Comment: Both your Sex and Skillset should probably be an [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum).  Would make your code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: What code sets the variable skillset? How do you expect it to get set to "EXIT"? Right now your code will loop forever.

Comment: skillset = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();     Reads user the user input

Comment: I would use a `IDictionary<string,string>` for looking up the value, instead of all the if/else if expressions. You can also make it more maintainable by using a factory method (probably). Something like `GetSkillSet(SkillSet skillset)`, where `SkillSet` is an enumeration.

You're calling all these SkillSet methods. Why not place your printing logic there?

Comment: @ColeConnelly:  That Readline is outside of your loop.  For example, if they type "bob" then your program enters a loop from which it will never return.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/). C# Console Applications only seem to have one kind of event, it fires when ctrl+c or ctrl+break happens. You could handle your skillset input/output logic in the function handler

You can read more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.cancelkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx

If you really need the word to be typed, you could capture everything that is typed in a special function, instead of using regular Console.ReadLine(). Something like this:

```
    public static string CustomReadLine()
    {

        ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
        string capturedInput = "";

        while (true)
        {

            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                break;
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                capturedInput += " ";
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                capturedInput = capturedInput.Remove(capturedInput.Length - 1);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write(capturedInput);
            }
            else
            {
                capturedInput += cki.KeyChar;
                Console.Write(cki.KeyChar);
            }

            if (capturedInput.ToUpper().Contains("SKILLSET"))
            {
                capturedInput = "";
                skillsetTyped();
                return "";
            }
        }

        return capturedInput;
}
```

then inside your Create_Character, do

```
...
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Are you male or female? (f/m): ");
        Sex = CustomReadLine();
    } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sex));
```

And finally, handle the skillset logic here

```
protected static void skillsetTyped()
{
    Console.Write("\nWrite your skillset capture/display logic here\n");
}
```

This is just a draft and has some minor bugs, but I believe it's close to what you really want.